# How to avoid eyestrain when working with mobiles?

Tags: eye

I've been a software engineer for around 20 years, the old monitors used to hurt my eyes but since the move to LCD monitors I haven't had any problems.

In the last year I've started working with mobile phones, since then I've noticed my eyes getting sore. I know to take regular breaks and stare into the distance, but is there any other advice with working on phones?

For Android I can hook the phone up to chrome and use it via chrome, but it's not as good. For the iphone I have to work on the iphone itself as we don't have macs.

Maybe a magnifying glass or phone holder for the monitor might help, so the phone is at eye level?